# How can I have a separate audio output that redirects to an audio input using PulseAudio?

Tags: pulseaudio

I've seen other threads post about redirecting the audio from their speakers as an input, which is easy enough, but I want a completely separate dummy audio device that pipes audio into its own new input. Basically trying to set up an equivalent to [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) but on Linux PulseAudio.

How can I get that set up?